# Is it possible to allow specific user or IP to bypass squidguard?

Tags: linux, debian, proxy, squid

Recently, I configured a raspberry as a little server. In particular I installed DHCP, squid proxy and squidGuard for log the network activity which pass through my raspberry. Actually i have a black list on squidGuard which denied the access to gamble websites.

My current OS version: **Linux raspberrypi 4.14.98-v7+ #1200 SMP Tue Feb 12 20:27:48 GMT 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux**.

Squid: **Version 3.5.23**, SquidGuard: **1.5 Berkeley DB 5.3.28: (September  9, 2013)**.

My **squid.conf** file:

```
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
redirect_program /usr/bin/squidGuard
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all
http_port 3128
cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 1000 16 256
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
```

My **squidGuard.conf** file:

```
dbhome /var/lib/squidguard/db
logdir /var/log/squidguard
time workhours {
    weekly mtwhf 08:00 - 16:30
    date *-*-01  08:00 - 16:30
}
src admin {
    ip              1.2.3.4  1.2.3.5
    user            root foo bar
    within          workhours
}

src foo-clients {
    ip    172.16.2.32-172.16.2.100 172.16.2.100 172.16.2.200
}

src bar-clients {
    ip    172.16.4.0/26
}

dest good {   }
dest local {    }
dest porn {   }
dest gamble{
    domainlist    gamble/domains
    urllist    gamble/urls
}

acl {
    admin {
            pass     any
    }
    foo-clients within workhours {
            pass     good !in-addr !porn any
    } else {
            pass any
    }
    bar-clients {
            pass    local none
    }
    default {
            pass    !gamble any
            redirect http://admin.foo.bar.de/cgi-bin/blocked.cgi? 
                     clientaddr=%a&clientname=%n
                     &clientuser=%i&clientgroup=%s&targetgroup=%t&url=%u
    }
}
```

After all of these infos, for example there is user A and user B, A can visit gamble websites whereas B not.

Is there any way to achieve this result using squid/squidGuard? But i don't want that user A bypass the proxy, only allow him to surf on gamble websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any way to achieve this result using squid/squidGuard? But i don't want that user A bypass the proxy, only allow him to surf on gamble websites?
**yes it is possible**

here is the sample code if the A user using IP in the range foo-clients

```
src foo-clients {
    ip    172.16.2.32-172.16.2.100 172.16.2.100 172.16.2.200
}
```

```
acl {
    admin {
            pass     any
    }
    foo-clients {
            pass     good gamble !porn any
    } 
    bar-clients {
            pass    local none
    }
    default {
            pass    !gamble any
            redirect http://admin.foo.bar.de/cgi-bin/blocked.cgi? 
                     clientaddr=%a&clientname=%n
                     &clientuser=%i&clientgroup=%s&targetgroup=%t&url=%u
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of IP address, i can use the username? Because I have DHCP enabled.

Comment: yes you can, but you have to create group of users.
few years ago, i was integrated with my Active Directory Domain Server, so it is more dynamic & flexible :)

Comment: Great, do you have any link or source where i can read more?